# Show content that referenced to a user to him

Tags: views, entities, users

In my site I have a content type with a **user reference field**.

I want to create a *view* to show  contents to a user that are referenced by this user reference field.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a content type with a user reference field and you want to display a list of these content types that reference the currently logged in user, you could create a view, Filter it on published nodes of that type, and then add in an Argument, which would be the field in question, and then supply as the default argument the uid of the currently logged in user.  Then just set up whatever Fields you want displayed and you should be on your way.

Comment: it not really work! I have 3 user reference field.I want to chose different person per it.but now it work just When I chose in all of three field one person.I want to show content to persons that that chose in one off field.please help me soon!

Comment: So, you have a content type with three fields, each of which are user reference fields, and you want to be able to put a user in one of those fields and have views return results upon that, even if the other two fields are empty?

Comment: tank's,solved :D